# I am trying to install openssl package in R using Ubuntu 18.04 without success

Tags: r, openssl

I try to install the Openssl package in R (using RStudio in Ubuntu 18.04), but I get the error "undefined symbol: RSA_pkey_ctx_ctrl":

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘openssl’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/home/danilo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/openssl/libs/openssl.so':
  /home/danilo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/openssl/libs/openssl.so: undefined symbol: RSA_pkey_ctx_ctrl
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/home/danilo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/openssl’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘openssl’ had non-zero exit status.
```

I have already tried to install through both RStudio and Terminal, but as I am relatively new to Ubuntu, I did not have any success. I have the tar.gz file downloaded, but I don't know what should I do with it.

I actually want to use packages `httr` and `ggmap`, but they both require `openssl`.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install r-cran-openssl` -- the package [is part of the distribution](https://packages.ubuntu.com/r-cran-openssl) and ready pre-made as a binary.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try in terminal:

```sh
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

and after that try to install package openssl in R again.